# How to update List Fragment Periodically with LoaderManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to update List Fragment Periodically? I need to query data from SQLite Database and Update ListFragment. For this,can i use Loader Manager?

Am i correct,If i use **Loader Manager** in my List Fragment,whenever new data availale in sqlite database,it will load that data to my List Fragment Asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ListFragment implement [Loader.Callbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html).

On the onLoadFinished callback, do something like this;

```
onLoadFinished (Loader<List<D>> loader, List<D> result){  
    setListAdapter(new YourListAdapter(esult));  
}
```

Obviously this would depend on what adapter you use and so on.

Call it trough `getLoaderManagger.initLoader(int id, Bundle params, , LoaderCallbacks<D> callback);`, passing a unique id everytime you call it (with a value based on current time, for example).

Besides that, you would need a Timer, which TimerTask run() method would simply init the loader.